# how to convert datetime datatype to string in asp.net + vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to convert datetime to string. I have declared DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE as datetime in SQL server database and want to convert it to string in my source code. I am getting the error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'"

Here my source code:

```
If rdmysql.IsDBNull(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE")) = False Then
    Dim ServiceDate As Date = rdmysql.GetString(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE"))
    ServiceTxt.Text = Format(ServiceDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This column is of type `datetime`, so you cant use `GetString` but [`GetDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim ServiceDate As Date = rdmysql.GetDateTime(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE"))
```

Instead of the VB6 `Format` function i would use .NET:

```
ServiceTxt.Text = ServiceDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

or simple and readable (if your culture uses `-` as date delimiter):

```
ServiceTxt.Text = ServiceDate.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: @hasni: you're welcome. Remember to accept if your question is solved.